# Why am I getting this "list index out of range" error?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, index-error

`def numline(name)` returns a number of lines in of a text file

`def anyLine(name,n)` returns any line of a text file and each line (on my text file) have three tabs ('\t')

If I run the program without the loop, I get my desired answer, but when I use for loop I keep getting the error

> (dictConcepts[a_string[0], a_string[2].rstrip('\n')] = a_string[1]
> IndexError: list index out of range)

This is my code:

```
def main(name):

    for i in range(0, numLine(name)):
        a_string = anyLine(name, i).split('\t')
        dictConcepts[a_string[0], a_string[2].rstrip('\n')] = a_string[1]

    for key in dictConcepts:
         print(key, ':', dictConcepts[key])
```

Comment: There are three indexing operations in the line throwing the error. Obviously, one of them is out of bounds. You **must** provide a [mcve]. And honestly, you need to put in the *bare-minimum* effort into debuggin this yourself... have you tried seeing what `a_string` actually is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, if:

```
a_string = anyLine(name, i).split('\t')
```

does not produce at least a length three list, (i.e. `\t` is present twice in the line) your code will fail with an index error.

You can program a `try`/`except` so you're not indexing things that do not exist:

```
a_string = anyLine(name, i).split('\t')
try:
    dictConcepts[a_string[0], a_string[2].rstrip('\n')] = a_string[1]
except IndexError:
    print('something is not right here')
```

Comment: mabye `print('something is not right here, expected 3 items, got', a_string)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yea, whatever the programmer wants to put there- just the general idea!